# Find the dimensions with the box of volume $1,000cm^3$ with minimal surface area.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Setting it up:

$V=lwh$ or $1000=lwh$

Solve for h:

$h=\frac{1000}{lw}$

$SA= 2lw+\frac{2000}{w}+\frac{2000}{l} = 0$

Find the partial derivatives:

$S_l = 2w-\frac{2000}{l^2}=0$ solving gives $w = \frac{1000}{l^2}$

$S_w = 2l-\frac{2000}{w^2}=0$ solving gives $l=\frac{1000}{w^2}$

S we have $\frac{1000}{w^2}=\frac{1000}{l^2} = 0$ we can divide by 1000 and clearly the denominators must be equal so, $w=l$.

Now is this all correct up to here and how do I find my values from here

I did:

if $l=w$ then: 
$SA= 2w^2+\frac{4000}{2w}$ getting like denominators gives $\to \frac{4w^3+4000}{2l}=0$

which leads to $4w^3=-4000 \to w=\pm10$ which really means w=10 since we can't have a negative dimension, serious question does anyone know what that would mean?

So we come to the conclusion that $V=100h$ or $10000=100h \to h=10$

Therefor a box a box with volume $1000 cm^3$ and dimensions $10cm^3\times10cm^3\times10cm^3$ gives the minimal surface area. We conjecture that this is true for all box's.

A box with any set volume will have minimal surface area when the box is a cube.

proof:

let, $V=\Phi$ and let $SA=\Psi$ for all $\Phi,\Psi \in \Bbb R$

then:

$h=\frac{\Phi}{lw}$

$\Psi= 2wl+\frac{2\Phi}{w}+\frac{2\Phi}{l}$

$\Psi_l=2w-\frac{2\Phi}{l^2}$ $\to w=\frac{\Phi}{l^2}$

$\Psi_w= 2l-\frac{2\Phi}{w}$ $\to l=\frac{\Phi}{w^2}$

$\frac{\Phi}{w^2} = \frac{\Phi}{l^2} = 0$

$\frac{1}{w^2} = \frac{1}{l^2} = 0$

and clearly the denominators must be equal so we get

$w=l$

WLOG:

$\Phi= 2wh$

so $h=\frac{\Phi}{2w}$ and $w=\frac{\Phi}{2h}$ so clearly w=h=l and the dimensions are:

$w=l=\frac{\Phi}{2h}$ and $h=\frac{\Phi}{2w}$

Now notice the Surface area equation is symmetric about w=l does this mean that any symmetric(WRT two variables) equation of three variables will have exactly one critical point? or is it dependent on the power of the variables where there is some formula between the number symmetric variables, the powers, and the critical points? is this a theorem?

Comment: What does WLOG mean? I checked your proof for the case of the 10x10x10 and it seems fine. I couldn't read the rest but it is true that the SA is minimal for a cubic box.

Comment: @RSerrao WLOG means "without loss of generality"